# How do I set returned Firebase data to a $scope variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to output all of the books in the book node on my home page. What I need is an array of objects that contain all of the books in the book node so that I can loop through them using the ng-repeat directive in AngularJs. In the code below, when I console log the data, I get an object of objects, which cannot be used with ng-repeat. Another issue that I am having is when I try to output the $scope.allBooks variable on to the page, nothing appears. Can anyone help me with this?

Using Javascript SDK not Angularfire
https://firebase.google.com/docs/

```
// Main Controller
firebase.database().ref('books').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();

    $scope.allBooks = data;
    console.log(data);
});


// Book Node in Firebase
books : {
    id : {
        title: 'The Hunger Games',
        author: 'Suzanne'
    },
    id : {
        title: 'Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix',
        author: 'J.K.'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use angularfire you'll need to let angular know to run an update.

```
// Main Controller
firebase.database().ref('books').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();

    $scope.allBooks = data;
    console.log(data);
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Just add in the `$scope.$apply()` to let angular know to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly use objects with `ng-repeat` on objects with the proper syntax. This is explained on the [ng-repeat documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

But this will break the order of items, so it's definitely not a recommended approach. Instead, you should use the [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) method to iterate children in the proper order, and build the array yourself.

---

If you use the Firebase JS SDK directly, Angular will not be notified of the changes to your data. You must trigger a digest cycle manually, so the scopes can be re-evaluated.

One of the ways to do it is by using $timeout to wrap scope manipulations. This was named a best practice in the [old Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/beyond-angularfire.html).

```
   // Main Controller
   firebase.database().ref('books').on('value', function(snapshot) {
       var data = snapshot.val();
       console.log(data);
       $timeout(function() {
           $scope.allBooks = data;
       });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @vzsg